# Ansible Replacement in file

Tags: ansible

I have a question about the replace line or word by ansible replace the module.

I can use this module to replace some specific words e.g **Windows** -> **Linux**

I want to know how to define the path and make it replace with a different path? Also, it could be meet the requirements like that can accept whitespace/non-whitespace and somewhere in the string

The file syntax before:

```sh
Andy   /home/tmp/users/notchange
Bob    /home/tmp/users/ready
Candy  /home/tmp/users/non
```

After running Ansible playbook to replace paths:

```sh
Andy   /home/tmp/users/admin
Bob    /home/tmp/users/normal
Candy  /home/tmp/users/remove
```

My Ansible Playbook(Not Work):

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Find All Configuration file
      ansible.builtin.replace:
        path: '/home/tmp/text1.txt'
        regexp: '\b{{ item.regexpPath }}\b'
        replace: '{{ item.absolutePath }}'
      loop:
        - {regexpPath: '/home/tmp/users/notchange', absolutePath: '/home/tmp/users/admin'}
        - {regexpPath: '/home/tmp/users/ready', absolutePath: '/home/tmp/users/normal'}
        - {regexpPath: '/home/tmp/users/non', absolutePath: '/home/tmp/users/remove'}
```

Comment: You can't use ``\b`` word boundary with ``'/home ...'`` because the path starts by ``'/'`` which does not match  ``\w`` *alphanumeric: [0-9a-zA-Z_]*. What boundaries would you like to accept?

Comment: I want to change the path if the path meets the regex, but maybe the line have some whitespace so I want that can also accept the whitespace/non-whitespace in the path before or after

Comment: And i removed the \b in start of regexp then it works now. Thx bro

Comment: The question now would be whether, for example,  ``/usr/local/home/tmp/users/notchange`` should match the *regexp* or not. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: **"*Accept whitespace/non-whitespace*"**

A: The problem is that Python regex special sequence *`\b`* does not match slash *`/`* at the beginning of the paths.

```yaml
        regexp: '\b{{ item.regexpPath }}\b'
```

Having run the task as is you should have seen (at localhost only)

```yaml
TASK [Find All Configuration file] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'regexpPath': '/home/tmp/users/notchange', 'absolutePath': '/home/tmp/users/admin'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'regexpPath': '/home/tmp/users/ready', 'absolutePath': '/home/tmp/users/normal'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'regexpPath': '/home/tmp/users/non', 'absolutePath': '/home/tmp/users/remove'})
```

The task shall work as expected if you remove the first *`\b`* from the *regexp*

```yaml
        regexp: '{{ item.regexpPath }}\b'
```

Running the play now with the options *`--check --diff`* you should see the replacement as expected

```yaml
TASK [Find All Configuration file] *****************************************
--- before: text1.txt
+++ after: text1.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-Andy   /home/tmp/users/notchange
+Andy   /home/tmp/users/admin
 Bob    /home/tmp/users/ready
 Candy  /home/tmp/users/non

changed: [localhost] => (item={'regexpPath': '/home/tmp/users/notchange', 'absolutePath': '/home/tmp/users/admin'})
--- before: text1.txt
+++ after: text1.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 Andy   /home/tmp/users/notchange
-Bob    /home/tmp/users/ready
+Bob    /home/tmp/users/normal
 Candy  /home/tmp/users/non

changed: [localhost] => (item={'regexpPath': '/home/tmp/users/ready', 'absolutePath': '/home/tmp/users/normal'})
--- before: text1.txt
+++ after: text1.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 Andy   /home/tmp/users/notchange
 Bob    /home/tmp/users/ready
-Candy  /home/tmp/users/non
+Candy  /home/tmp/users/remove

changed: [localhost] => (item={'regexpPath': '/home/tmp/users/non', 'absolutePath': '/home/tmp/users/remove'})
```